# Solving trigonometric equation with both a dependent within a cos and outside

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to solve the equation $0.8t+10\cdot \cos⁡(\frac{t}{2})=0$
However i end up with something like this:
$$-6,25=\frac{(\cos^{-1}t)}{t}$$
How is something like this solved? I feel like I am missing a simple step or something.

Comment: i have found $$t\approx -.3000940041$$

Comment: You can set $y=t/2$ and then you will obtain $\frac{\cos y}{ y} = - 0.16$. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos+y+%2F+y+%3D+-0.16

Comment: Your second equation is not equivalent to your first.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the second equation of yours is correct, you know that:
$$-6.25=\frac{(\cos^{-1}t)}{t}\implies$$

$$\implies-6.25 = \frac{\pi}{2x} + \frac{i\log(\sqrt{1-x^2}+ix)}{x}$$

By running the following [Mathematica program](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/a238931b-48fb-45c8-ab39-33573847a8e7#sidebar=compute):

```
TrigToExp[-6.25 == ArcCos[x]/x]
```

We obtain the raw value:
$$x\approx-0.300094004058679$$

You probably made a mistake though, and therefore you can find the values from the original equation with number computational methods (like Newton's method of calculus)

Answer (score 0):

There is no "closed form" solution.  There are five real solutions to the equation
$0.8 t + 10 \cos(t/2) = 0$, approximately
$$-12.49116333,\; -11.99716416,\; -2.705293407,\; 3.751175051,\; 8.029608133$$
They can be found using numerical methods, e.g. Newton's method.

You made an error in finding the second equation.

Comment: So you are saying the only way to find the solutions is by solving numerically? Are there a certain way this can be proven or something?

Comment: "Closed form" is not a precisely defined concept.  Even if you gave a precise definition of what functions are allowed, I doubt that it would be possible to prove.  All I can prove is that the solutions are transcendental numbers (by the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem).

Comment: Every method that returns an explicit number is a "numerical method".  There are alternatives to Newton-type methods, e.g. a solution $t$ of $x t + \cos(t/2) = 0$ satisfies the differential equation $(x - \sin(t/2)/2) t' + t = 0$, which can be solved numerically or by series.